# RoR: How do I define @microposts two different ways in the same view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to put a search (microposts) function into my app. All of the ways to do it involve giving the definition

```
@microposts=Micropost.search(params[:search])
```

or something like that. you always have to define @microposts in the microposts_controller.rb

The problem is that I already have

```
def home
     @microposts=Micropost.all
end
```

because initially the home page is just a list of all microposts. How can I change the definition once the user uses the search function. Is that the only way? Do I need an if then statement.

like if they press search @microposts=Micropost.search(params[:search]) else @microposts=Micropost.all? how can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a search method in your Micropost model? You could out an if/else statement in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the page is initially loaded, i guess the `params[:search]` was not present. so you can try:

```
if params[:search].present?
  @microposts=Micropost.search(params[:search])
else 
  @microposts=Micropost.all
```